# Is it literally possible to strengthen the fingers directly through finger exercises, or are they in conjunction with the hands mainly?

Tags: exercise

I have seen many finger exercises, but some have noted that fingers are conjoined with hands in muscularity and use, so can you really strengthen or isolate the fingers indirectly from the hand muscles, or must they work in conjunction always?

I know there are different types of grip, like pinch, crush, static endurance application, etc.

But regarding the fingers specifically, because I notice some people just have really tough fingers aside from strong hands, and although my hands aren't "weak" my fingers aren't actually strong, and are pretty frail.

So my question is, are the fingers conjoined 100% with the hands, or can they be worked on more directly through exercises without worrying about over working hand muscles interchangeably?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What parts of the hand are you talking about if you not fingers?  Your palm?  Your wrists?

Answer (score 2):

All of the muscles that control your fingers are in your forearms. The few muscles in your hand control just your thumb.

"Finger strength" and grip are related, more so, regardless of the type of grip, they are all exercised in pretty much the same way. So anything related to holding heavy things, like deadlifts, farmers walks, or shrugs will all exercise your grip/pinch/crush ability as well as specific exercises, like grip strengtheners.

Comment: "All of the muscles that control your fingers are in your forearms. The few muscles in your hand control just your thumb."  Although this may be practical as it relates to grip and weight lifting, this is not completely accurate, esp. with fine motor control. For accuracy, you may want to include the [intrinsic muscles](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-intrinsic-muscles-of-the-wrist-and-hand.html) - the interossei, lumbricals, and the hypothenar muscles in addition to the thumb or thenar muscles.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are muscles in your hands themselves, most of them are in your forearms. As an awesome example, check out rock climber Adam Ondra at 4:02 in this video, where he's traversing the ceiling of a cave by gripping stalactites: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOC15Atu39U . You can pretty clearly see that because of the kind of grip he's attained, his forearms are huge compared to his upper arms.

But training isn't just about muscles. You're also building the strength of your connective tissue, and there is a lot of that in your hands.